# JvectorMap rerendering proper markers after setState reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jvectormap

The problem I'm having is whenever the data that is passed into the `jvectormap` changes, the map doesn't reflect the changes.

Inside my state, I have two sets of data: `data1` and `data2`. Inside my render method, I have a button where once clicked, it'll change `this.state.data1` to have the same contents as `this.state.data2` since the map takes this.state.data1 as the value for `markers`. Here is my render function:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a
          href="#"
          onClick={() =>
            this.setState({ data1: this.state.data2 }, () =>
              console.log(this.state.data1)
            )
          }
        >
          Click
        </a>
        <div style={{ width: 500, height: 300 }}>
          <VectorMap
            map={"world_mill"}
            backgroundColor="#FFFFF"
            markerStyle={{
              initial: {
                fill: "#FFFF",
                stroke: "#383f47"
              }
            }}
            series={{
              markers: [
                {
                  attribute: "r",
                  scale: [5, 20],
                  values: [60, 6, 54],
                  normalizeFunction: "polynomial"
                }
              ]
            }}
            regionStyle={{
              initial: {
                fill: "#128da7"
              },
              hover: {
                fill: "#A0D1DC"
              }
            }}
            markers={this.state.data1}
            ref="map"
            containerStyle={{
              width: "100%",
              height: "100%"
            }}
            containerClassName="map"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The whole code is simple and can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/2vx2k1vl9n. 
As you can see, in the onClick method for the button, I print `data1` after setting the state in order to make sure that its value changes which it does, but it's not being reflected on the map. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is basically not in your code.
I just went to *react-jvectormap* repo and had a look at the code because I suspect that there is something denying re-rendering.

Turns out the map isn't being rendered by ReactJS, instead it is being rendered by jQuery.

I went and forked the project and altered its code so that it would work with the example given above.

I'll do a pull request to their repo, meanwhile, you can try and use my version here:
https://github.com/seifsg/react-jvectormap

And this is the file that I made the change to, you might just want to copy and paste it to its right place within your node_modules folder:
https://github.com/seifsg/react-jvectormap/blob/master/src/lib/components/VectorMap.js

So to have it working with your code:

- Copy the modified file to the corresponding node_modules directory
- In the same directory, execute `npm i` then `npm run build` that should generate a new build file and should make your changes work.

Here is an example using the build file only: codesandbox.io/s/kw90mx7647

Comment: Hello @Seif Sgayer thank you for your response and I will try this as soon as I get home. Is the only change you made was adding the componentDidUpdate() method?

Comment: Yes exactly, that was missing.

Comment: Hey @Seif Sgayer, I tried what you suggested. I copy pasted your VectorMap.js within node_modules and reset the server and tried. It's still behaving the same way

Comment: I also deleted everything from the VectorMap.js and re-ran my program and it ran the same way...I'm editing node_modules/react-jvectormap/src/lib/components/VectorMap.js ...could it be possible this is the wrong file?

Comment: @jim seems like their npm version is slightly different that the github. They use different main file and they use webpack. So for now:

* Copy the modified file to the corresponding node_modules directory

* In the same directory, execute `npm i` then `npm run build`

that should generate a new build file and should make your changes work.


Here is an example using the build file only:

https://codesandbox.io/s/kw90mx7647

Comment: thank you so much you're an expert! Can you include the comment above in the answer so that I can mark it as correct and reward you the bounty points

Comment: @jim I did that. Thank you!

Comment: Hey @Seif Sgayer, I downloaded your code sandbox and tried running it on my machine and get multiple errors such as `'define' is not defined ` and `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression`. Would you know why it works in the sandbox and not locally on my machine?

Comment: Probably due to an environment change. I don't know exactly the cause, however, my pull request got accepted and merged. You don't need now to copy and paste the code manually. You should just update your **react-jvectormap** and even your original codesandbox should work now.

Comment: all I did was click the download button in codesandbox and ran the program on my machine after I downloaded it....By pull request are you talking about you're github version? Also what do you mean update react-jvectormap when you replaced it with the `react-jvectormap-new-build` component? Wouldn't I be able to leave it the same?...Sorry about these questions I'm a noob

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to work on forked stuff, here is a work around.

First create a boolean state to how/hide the map:

```
const [isShowMap, setIsShowMap] = useState(true);
```

Attached this state to show/hide the map html:

```
{ isShowMap && <VectorMap... }
```

On any change in props or any data, just turn this flag off and on again with setTimeout:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  setIsShowMap(false);
  setTimeout(()=>{
    setIsShowMap(true);
  })
}, [prop1, prop2]);
```

As it is just a work around, you will experience a tittle flicker.